# Google colab fails to read file: OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

After I successfully uploaded my local files to google colab using

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

I want to read the files using

```
signal_files = open(uploaded['StatsTCSVIXMeanRev_01042021.csv'], 'r')
df1 = read_csv1(signal_files)
```

But then it gives me the error: `OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long` and printed all the csv file entries and considered them as the "file name". I searched for this error on stackoverflow, but I didn't understand their explanation. Is there an easy way to get my files read on google colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I do not need the line `signal_files = open(uploaded['filename'], 'r')` to read the colab file. I can directly read the file using pandas `df1 = read_csv1(filename)`.